# gRaphael pie chart dynamic size

Tags: javascript, jquery, pie-chart, graphael

I want to enlarge [gRaphael pie chart](http://g.raphaeljs.com/piechart.html) after some event, click for example. But gRaphael pie chart is creating after window load with static width and heigh. Is it possible to dynamic redraw it in real time?

My code:

```
var myRadius;

myRadius = 200;

var myChart = Raphael("myChartDiv"), 
    myChartPie = myChart.piechart(
        myRadius, // cx
        myRadius, // cy
        myRadius, //Radius
        [70, 30], //Data    
        {           
        colors: ["#eb5e57", "#ebad50"],         
        stroke: "#f1eeea"       
        }
    );

$('#myButton').click(function(){
     myRadius = 500; 
     myChart.clear(); //Clear current canvas
     // Do something to insert myChart with new myRadius
});
```

UPD
Ofcourse I can remove after click current chart and create new, but it's not a way, because I will need to back original size after other click.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to clear & redraw your pie as on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k38hM/).

```
var myRadius;

myRadius = 200;

var myChart = Raphael("myChartDiv"), 
    myChartPie = myChart.piechart(
        myRadius, // cx
        myRadius, // cy
        myRadius, //Radius
        [70, 30], //Data    
        {           
            colors: ["#eb5e57", "#ebad50"],         
            stroke: "#f1eeea"       
        }
    );

$('#myButton').click(function(){
    if(myRadius == 200)
         myRadius = 500; 
    else
        myRadius = 200;
    myChart.clear();
    myChartPie = myChart.piechart(
        myRadius, // cx
        myRadius, // cy
        myRadius, //Radius
        [70, 30], //Data    
        {           
            colors: ["#eb5e57", "#ebad50"],         
            stroke: "#f1eeea"       
        }
    );
});
```

Of course, data and options should be factorized and put in global scope for usability.